Issue with testclass
I have the following Apex class:
public class sendAnEmailSettle {

  @InvocableMethod(label='Settlement send' description='sends an email')

  public static void sendEmailWithAttachment(List<id> listofQuoteHeader){   

    Map<Id, Settlement__c> quotesMap =  new Map<Id, Settlement__c>([

      SELECT id FROM Settlement__c WHERE Id IN :listofQuoteHeader

    ]);

    List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailMessages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for(Id QuoteHeaderid :listofQuoteHeader){

      PageReference pref= page.Settlement;

      pref.getParameters().put('id',(Id)QuoteHeaderid);

      pref.setRedirect(true);

      Attachment attachment = new Attachment();      

      Blob b;

      if ( Test.isRunningTest() ){

        b = blob.valueOf('hello world');

      } else {

        b = pref.getContentAsPDF();

      }

      attachment.Body = b;

      attachment.Name = Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') + ' ' + 'Settle' + '.pdf';

      attachment.IsPrivate = false;

      attachment.ParentId = QuoteHeaderid;

      attachment.Name='Sign.png';

      attachments.add(attachment);

      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach= new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

      attach.setFileName('AttachmentEmailFile.pdf');

      attach.setBody(b);

      semail.setSubject('Settle print ' + Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'));

      String[] emailIds= new String[]{'set.prt@bwrecycling.com'}; 
    
  //String[] emailIds= new String[]{'shlomibizaoui@gmail.com'};
      semail.setToAddresses(emailIds);

      semail.setPlainTextBody('Settlement');

      semail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attach});

      emailMessages.add(semail);

    }

    insert attachments;

    if ( Test.isRunningTest() == FALSE ){

      Messaging.sendEmail(emailMessages);

    }

  }

}

The test class that I have is the following:

@isTest
private class sendAnEmailSettleTests {
  static final Integer NUM_RECORDS = 200;

  @TestSetup
  static void makeData(){
    List<Selement__c> testRecords = new List<Selement__c>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < NUM_RECORDS; i++){
        Selement__c c = new Selement__c(Receiving__c = 'a0R8Z00000PGOtN');
        testRecords.add(c);
    }

    insert testRecords;
  }

  @isTest
  static void sendEmailWithAttachmentUnitTest() {
    List<Selement__c> testRecords = queryChecks();
    Map<Id,Selement__c> testRecordsMap = new Map<Id,Selement__c>(testRecords);

    Assert.isTrue(testRecords.size() == NUM_RECORDS , 'The number of test records is not correct');

    Test.startTest();
    List<Id> ids = new List<Id>(testRecordsMap.keySet());
    sendAnEmailSele.sendEmailWithAttachment(ids);
    Test.stopTest();

    List<Attachment> attachments = [
      SELECT Id
      FROM Attachment
      WHERE ParentId IN :testRecordsMap.keySet()
    ];

    Assert.isTrue(attachments.size() == testRecordsMap.size(), 'The sendEmailWithAttachments method did not insert an Attachments properly');
  }

  static List<Selement__c> queryChecks(){
        List<Selement__c> checks = [
            SELECT Id
            FROM Selement__c
            LIMIT :NUM_RECORDS
        ];

        return checks;
    }
}

But I am getting an error

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void sendEmailWithAttachment(List) from the type sendAnEmailSele


The test class line
sendAnEmailSele.sendEmailWithAttachment(ids);

references a status method in class sendAnEmailSele
but the class is named differently
public class sendAnEmailSettle {

Some other notes

Your test class references an Sobject called Selement__c yet in the code-under-test, this sobject is Settlement__c
Class names should be initial caps
Variable listofQuoteHeader should be better-named - use quoteHeaderIds
Instead of if ( Test.isRunningTest() == FALSE), use if (!Test.isRunningTest())

